# CCLabelTTF character interval

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Can we set interval in pixels between characters in text using CCLabelTTF in iOS cocos2d? Any ideas about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In custom fonts you can edit the run length (width) of each character in the TTF file. If you're not using a custom made font, you can't change the run length of characters.